# Changing PHP developed backend to Java spring boot

Tags: java, php, ajax, spring-boot

I am not sure if this question gonna be considered as duplicated or not, but I wasn't able to find my answer even by googling or through out the QA suggested topics on the SOF. So here I go asking my question:

I have developed a website with Javascript, PHP , AJAX that's using JSON to talk to eachother. And now the client is asking me to change all PHP backend to Spring Boot. That means I gonna talk to the HTML and  Javascript and MySql using Java EE Spring Boot and I am not sure how I gonna do it.  My main problems are:

1- Is it possible to parse data from Java to the jQuery using JSON ? I mean I  retrive data from the MySql and then send it back to the .php file.

The PHP example would be:

```
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;
```

2- Is it possible to get the parsed the respons from the JAVA through the jQuery :

```
jQuery.ajax({

        type:"post",
        dataType:"json",
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {action: 'submit_data', info: info},
        success: function(getParsedVAL) {
           // the variable getParsedVAL is comming from the JAVA file
            successmessage = 'Data was succesfully captured';
            $("label#successmessage").text(successmessage);
        },
        error: function(getParsedVAL) {
           // the variable getParsedVAL is comming from the JAVA file
            successmessage = 'Error';
            $("label#successmessage").text(successmessage);
        },
    });
success: function(getParsedVAL) {
    // the variable getParsedVAL is comming from the JAVA file
    successmessage = 'Data was succesfully captured';
}
```

Comment: Q1- YES - Q2. YES

Comment: If you dont have wired php and js together in one file, it should be easy. Also if you have used some framework (eg. symfony is kinda similar to spring) it should be easy and quick.

Comment: @Eakethet Thanks, I have just edited the question. My JS ajax is an external file parsing to an external PHP that is executing the mysql query and handeling it back to the JS file then the JS file does the needed work.

Comment: @RiggsFolly could you guide me through it? Could you introduce me any specific tutorial? Thanks

Comment: @Pavel so most probably you are doing some kind of "API", have a look at eg. REST api with spring, you send request to your php and gets response

Comment: @Eakethet yes you are right, as you mentioned it is possible to send the request to a php file through the REST but the problem is that the PHP should be replaced with the Java. So jQuery should send the request to a JSP file the JSP file talk to the MySql DB and send the respond back to the jQuery AJAX . In the above example url: myAjax.ajaxurl, should be  url: myJSPfile.jsp   and then myJSPfile.jsp should send the result back to success: function(getParsedVAL)    That's what I am trying to find a tutorial about.

Comment: @Pavel for start look there - https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ and connect it with hibernate with your db.

Comment: @Eakethet isn't hibernate for sql? I didn't know it goes with mysql too.

Comment: @Pavel MySQL is database system, SQL is (database) language. So hibernate goes with this database system and provide you layer above, so you can use ORM, hql (hybernate query language) instead of using pure SQL statements

Comment: @Eakethet got it, Thanks for the link will go through it.

Comment: And thanks for the person downgraded the question instead of helping. :)

Answer (score 0):

I’m actually transitioning to spring boot from php. Spring boot actually encodes the java object to json automatically. If you developed the back end with some lightweight framework with routing and model controller structure you can easily convert it to spring boost